# cannot run CocoaPods as root

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-maps, podfile

I'm using Windows 10 x64, i'm trying to use `react-native-maps`, once i want to make a pod file i face this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>           4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/pod:23:in '
>           3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/pod:23:in load'
>           2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0/bin/pod:55:in
>   '
>           1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:47:in
>   run'
>   C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in
>   `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)

I have installed different versions of cocoapods but always i face the same error